# React Router 4 How do I redirect programmatically inside a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a singinUser function which is called when user clicks the submit button. I want the user to redirect to another url when fetching the data is completed. In previous versions of react, I used to use `browserHistory` from `'react-router'`. What should I do in react-router 4?

```
import axios from 'axios';
    const ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3090';

    export const signinUser = ({ email, password }) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/signin`, { email, password })
                .then(response =>{
                    //I want to redirect
                })
                .catch(err=>{

                })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is personally how I perform a redirect for protected routes in my application:

```
const GuestRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <WebServiceContextConsumer>
    {
      context =>
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={props =>
            context.auth.getUser() 
              ? (<Redirect to={{pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location }}} />) 
              : (<Component {...props} />)
          }
        />
    }
  </WebServiceContextConsumer>
);
```

You need to separate your view from your logic. Perform your whatever call, then uses promises to catch the response and handle it however you want in your View component.